# Finding the Taylor series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{e^{z}-1}{z}$ around $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find the Taylor series expansion of $f(z)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{z}-1}{z}$ around $0$.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes you can accept an answer, if not tell us what you need.

Answer (score 5):

You know that 
$$\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
so 
$$\frac{\exp(z)-1}{z}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}$$

Comment: Do Taylor expansions work exactly the same for complex numbers a real numbers then?

Comment: Well as long as you have analytical functions yes. When you have isolated singularities it is a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Do you know how to find the taylor series expansion of $e^z$ around zero? Let $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. Then $$f(z)=(e^z-1)/z=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n-1)/z$$

Answer (score 1):

$$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\dots$$
Substract that by $1$ and divide $z$.